# Calendar dates different from the original scheduler IN OUTLOOK 2007 AND exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, calendar

I am using Windows Exchange 2003 on a Windows 2003 server machine. Now I do not know what have happened, all my users using Outlook 2007 are having calendar issues. When a user in my network receive a scheduler, the date is appearing different on outlook calendar from the one on the scheduler. For example if you send me a scheduler for Tuesday 2 October 2013, its appearing Monday 1 October 2013 on my calendar.

I have checked the timezone and the time on the server its all right. Anyone who can help me with please as I have spend a almost 2 days searching for an answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue isn't a patch/bug related to Exchange/Windows/Outlook that you haven't patched yet...

While the time and timezone on the server are important, Outlook relies on both local time and time zone (offsets) along with the remote/sending Outlook client's time and time zone offsets in order to correctly calculate the meeting time.

You can try using: [Time Zone tool for Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931667) and following that KB article fully (it's pretty long and extensive but informative).

Other factors such as users that have Activesync devices like iPhones/Androids can also affect this if they have a bug.

You would have to test it out locally though and see what is going on.  Without having full access to the systems this is something that is very difficult to answer for you without back and forth discussions.  If you get truly stuck the best recourse here would be to open a ticket with MS support and have them help you debug what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have downloaded the file and installed it on one of the windows machines this morning. It does not detect any time zone changes. Everything was working fine it only started last week with one user complaining then today all all users complaining too. Would you think might be server issue or is it maybe a bug in one o the machines in the network. I will be disabling device access for the mean time and see if this will help as you mentioned maybe it might be a an iphone or android in my network causing this issue.

Comment: Test using OWA instead of Outlook (on both sender and receiver).

Comment: So finally got it now. Here is how I got to work. After I accessed mail via OWA. I could see calendar working as it should. I then stopped all exchange services and restart them. I then reboot server and tested two meetings on the same machine I have tested with previously. For now this seems to be working. I will be going home now after spending the whole day googling this. I will see if I have an user tomorrow still with problem. Thank you for help once again. Will update you tomorrow